# How to pass the id via jquery in ajax call to perform delete operation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I want to delete the element of the list by clicking the delete button.

[image]

i have written the following ajax call for this:

```
             .ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : 'getVenueList',
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var sequenceNo = 1;
                    var tableData = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        tableData = "<tr><td>" + sequenceNo + "</td><td>"
                                               + data[i].venueName + "</td>";

                        tableData += ' <td><a class="no-line">&nbsp; <i id="Edit" title="Edit" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="font-size: 15px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </td>';
                        tableData += '  <td><a class="no-line" onclick="deleteVenue(this);">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red" ></span></a></td>';
                        tableData += ' <td style="display: none;"> '
                                + data[i].venueId + '</td></tr>';
                        sequenceNo = sequenceNo + 1;
                        $('#tbodyId').append(tableData);
                    }

                }

            });
```

on delete icon i have put the onclick function :

```
                  function deleteVenue(obj) {
                    var setValue = obj.id;

                    $
                            .ajax({
                                type : "GET",
                                async : false,
                                url : "deleteVenue",
                                data : {
                                    venueId : setValue
                                },
                                success : function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    window.location.reload();
                                    
                                }

                            });
                    }
```

but the issue is i am not getting the id in obj...

what is the solution?

Comment: If all you need is the ID, instead of `deleteVenue(this)`, try `deleteVenue(" + data[i].venueId  + ")`.  The `this` object won't be what you expect there so just pass the ID directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part.

```
<a class="no-line" onclick="deleteVenue(this);">
```

to

```
<a class="no-line" onclick="deleteVenue('+ data[i].venueId + ');">

function deleteVenue(id) {
                   
                    $.ajax({
                                type : "GET",
                                async : false,
                                url : "deleteVenue",
                                data : {
                                    venueId : id
                                },
                                success : function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    window.location.reload();
                                    
                                }

                            });
                    }
```